# VerbatimTextOutput() when hidden prevents the rest of the main body objects to be displayed in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I create the shiny app below creating function `TLH` and using it as a source file. In the main body I have a `verbatimTextOutput()` and `datatable()`. The strange thing is that when I delete the line `verbatimTextOutput("oResults"),` which creates the text the datatable is also hidden. I cannot understand why this happens but I want to use the TLH.r file to create the app and not put everything inside the app.r file since my actual app is more complex.

app.r

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
source("TLH.R")
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Investment Advisor Monitoring - Tax Loss Harvesting"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "pills",
                  tabPanel("Investment Selected", 
                           textInput("StockTicker3", "Enter Stock Symbol", value = "XOM"),
                           numericInput("StartAmount", "Start Amount", value = "10000")
                  )
                  
      ),
      
      
      
      actionButton("goButton", "Calculate")
      
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      h3('Results'),
      
      tabsetPanel(type = "pills",
                  
                  tabPanel("Tax Loss Harvesting Results",
                           verbatimTextOutput("oResults"),
                           dataTableOutput("oParametersTable")
                  )
                  
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  calc <- eventReactive(input$goButton,{
    
    TLH(input, output)
    
  })
  output$oResults <-  renderPrint({calc()})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

TLH.R

```
TLH <- function(input, output) {
  #Load Libraries
  
  ##Input Data
  
  StockTicker <- input$StockTicker3
  
  StartAmount <- input$StartAmount
  
  output$oParametersTable <- renderDataTable({
    
    ParametersTable <- data.frame(
      c("Stock Ticker", "Amount Invested"
        ),
      c(input$StockTicker, input$StartAmount
        )
    )
    
    colnames(ParametersTable)<- c("Parameters","Values")
    
    datatable(ParametersTable,
              options = list(
                paging =TRUE,
                pageLength =  15 
              ))})
  
  
  return("Tax Loss Harvest - Results")
}
```

Comment: I think if you would render your datatable it would show on our dashboard. You are only rendering the print in your server

Comment: I dont get you. Initially both are displayed. If I remove verbatimTextOutput none of them. How does this affect the table?

Comment: The rendering of the datatable happens inside TLH.R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to return a list of objects from the function `TLH`.  Then you can access and display each object as you wish.  Try this

```
TLH <- function(input, output) {
  #Load Libraries
  
  ##Input Data
  
  StockTicker <- input$StockTicker3
  
  StartAmount <- input$StartAmount
  
  #output$oParametersTable <- renderDataTable({
  
    ParametersTable <- data.frame(
      c("Stock Ticker", "Amount Invested"
      ),
      c(input$StockTicker, input$StartAmount
      )
    )
    
    colnames(ParametersTable)<- c("Parameters","Values")
    
    # datatable(ParametersTable,
    #           options = list(
    #             paging =TRUE,
    #             pageLength =  15 
    #           ))
    #})
  
  
  #return("Tax Loss Harvest - Results")
    return(list(
      val1 = ParametersTable,
      val2 = "Tax Loss Harvest - Results"
    ))
}

library(shiny)
library(DT)
# source("TLH.R")

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Investment Advisor Monitoring - Tax Loss Harvesting"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "pills",
                  tabPanel("Investment Selected", 
                           textInput("StockTicker3", "Enter Stock Symbol", value = "XOM"),
                           numericInput("StartAmount", "Start Amount", value = 10000)
                  )
      ),
      actionButton("goButton", "Calculate")
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      h3('Results'),
      
      tabsetPanel(type = "pills",
                  tabPanel("Tax Loss Harvesting Results",
                           #verbatimTextOutput("oResults"),
                           DTOutput("t1")
                  )
                  
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  calc <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    TLH(input, output)
  })
  
  output$t1 <- renderDT({
    datatable( calc()$val1, #ParametersTable,
              options = list(
                paging =TRUE,
                pageLength =  15 
              ))
  })
  
  output$oResults <-  renderPrint({calc()$val2})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```