# Create different sidebars for tabsetPanel() nested in other tabsetPanel() in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app below with 3 different tabs. I want each tab to have its own sidebar and I did this using `conditionalPanel()`. The first tab though (`InsiderTraining`) has 2 more tabs inside it (`Tab1,Tab2`) which I also want to have separated sidebars.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = tags$body(class="skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open",dashboardPage(
    options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
    header = dashboardHeader(title = "Investment Advisor Monitoring - Insider Trading",titleWidth = 450),
    
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(minified = F, collapsed = F,
                               h4("Investment Selected"),
                               uiOutput("mytab11"), uiOutput("mytab12"),uiOutput("mytab13"),uiOutput("mytab14")
                               
                               #textInput("StockTicker3", "Enter Stock Symbol 3", value = "AMZN")
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      h3('Results'),
      tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("InsiderTraining",
                           tabsetPanel(id="tabs2",
                                       tabPanel("tab1"),
                                       tabPanel("tab2"))),
                  tabPanel("Switching"),
                  tabPanel("Tax Loss Harvesting")
      )
    ),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(width = 300,
                                     h4("Insider Trading Parameters"),              
                                     uiOutput("mytab21"), uiOutput("mytab22")
                                     
                                     #selectInput("InsiderTradingModel3", "Insider Trading Model 3",
                                     #           c("Dynamic" = "Dynamic",
                                     #            "AI based" = "AIbased"))
    ),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  )),
  server = function(input, output) { 
    
    output$mytab11 <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs=="InsiderTraining"',
                         textInput("StockTicker", "Enter Stock Symbol", value = "NFLX"),
                         sliderInput('periods','Periods',min=1,max=120,value=60),
                         selectInput("mtvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(mtcars))
        ))
    })
    output$mytab12 <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs=="Switching"',
                         textInput("StockTicker2", "Enter Stock Symbol", value = "APPL"),
                         selectInput("cvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(cars))
        ))
    })      
    output$mytab13 <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs2=="Tab1"',
                         textInput("StockTicker3", "Enter Stock Symbol", value = "APPL"),
                         selectInput("cvar2", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(cars))
        ))
    })
    output$mytab14 <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs2=="Tab2"',
                         textInput("StockTicker4", "Enter Stock Symbol", value = "APPL"),
                         selectInput("cvar3", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(cars))
        ))
    }) 
    
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = tags$body(class="skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open",dashboardPage(
    options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
    header = dashboardHeader(title = "Investment Advisor Monitoring - Insider Trading",titleWidth = 450),
    
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(minified = F, collapsed = F,
                               h4("Investment Selected"),
                               #uiOutput("mytab11"), 
                               uiOutput("mytab12"),uiOutput("mytab13"),uiOutput("mytab14")
                               
                               #textInput("StockTicker3", "Enter Stock Symbol 3", value = "AMZN")
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      h3('Results'),
      tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("InsiderTraining",
                           tabsetPanel(id="tabs2",
                                       tabPanel("tab1"),
                                       tabPanel("tab2"))),
                  tabPanel("Switching"),
                  tabPanel("Tax Loss Harvesting")
      )
    ),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(width = 300,
                                     h4("Insider Trading Parameters"),              
                                     uiOutput("mytab21"), uiOutput("mytab22")
                                     
                                     #selectInput("InsiderTradingModel3", "Insider Trading Model 3",
                                     #           c("Dynamic" = "Dynamic",
                                     #            "AI based" = "AIbased"))
    ),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  )),
  server = function(input, output) { 
    
    output$mytab11 <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs=="InsiderTraining"',
                         textInput("StockTicker", "Enter Stock Symbol", value = "AAPL"),
                         sliderInput('periods','Periods',min=1,max=120,value=60),
                         selectInput("mtvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(mtcars))
        ))
    })
    output$mytab12 <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs=="Switching"',
                         textInput("StockTicker2", "Enter Stock Symbol", value = "NFLX"),
                         selectInput("cvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(cars))
        ))
    })      
    output$mytab13 <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs=="InsiderTraining" && input.tabs2=="tab1"',
                         textInput("StockTicker3", "Enter Stock Symbol", value = "APPL"),
                         sliderInput('periods3','Periods',min=1,max=120,value=30),
                         selectInput("cvar2", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(cars))
        ))
    })
    output$mytab14 <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs=="InsiderTraining" && input.tabs2=="tab2"',
                         textInput("StockTicker4", "Enter Stock Symbol", value = "FB"),
                         selectInput("cvar3", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(mtcars))
        ))
    })
    output$mytab21 <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs=="Switching"',
                         textInput("StockTicker", "Enter Stock Symbol", value = "ZM"),
                         sliderInput('periods','Periods',min=1,max=120,value=80),
                         selectInput("mtvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(pressure))
        ))
    })
    output$mytab22 <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs=="Tax Loss Harvesting"',
                         textInput("StockTicker", "Enter Stock Symbol", value = "TSLA"),
                         sliderInput('periods','Periods',min=1,max=120,value=100),
                         selectInput("mtvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(iris))
        ))
    })
    
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks with your shiny knowledge maybe u could explain this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69804708/verbatimtextoutput-when-hidden-prevents-the-rest-of-the-main-body-objects-to-b

Comment: It does not make sense to use conditionalPanels nested in renderUI. You should [use one or the other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77898613/9841389).